# Is there one command that will show me CPU, RAM, GPU, Disks, OS all at once on most distros?

Tags: linux, system-info

Currently at this point, I use:

cat /proc/cpuinfo
nvidia-smi OR lshw -C display
fdisk -l
cat /etc/lsb-release

Is there a faster way to get it all at once on redhats and debians?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `screen` to build a screen of information, boxes, where one command will be in one box and all of them visible on the screen at once.

You need to open few screens, make them smaller and put them in right places on the screen with commands issued in each screen part. You can do that with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: While this certainly could work, please do elaborate. `screen` is just a terminal multiplexer.

Answer (score 2):

Try apps like [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) ‒ self described as “a command-line system information tool [that] displays information about your operating system, software and hardware in an aesthetic and visually pleasing way.”